# Force on a circular current-carrying loop near a long wire

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current

This was a question I was wondering about, when I solved the similar problem of a square loop near a long wire.

> **Q** A long wire carries current $I_0$ and lies in the plane of a circular current-carrying loop of radius $R$. The loop carries current $i$ and its centre is at a distance of $a$ ($a>R$) from the wire. What is the magnitude of magnetic force exerted on the loop by the wire?

#### My attempt

I worked on the question on my own, and this is what I got.

- If the magnetic field were uniform, there would be no force on the loop, as it is a closed figure.
- However, that isn't the case here. So, I proceeded via integration, but the solution was nowhere in sight.
- Since $\vec{dF}=i(\vec{dl}×\vec{B})$, and based on the conditions given, I figured out that the magnetic force on any current element must be *perpendicular* to it, and *in the plane of the coil.*
- Also, the net magnetic force on *two symmetrically placed current elements* must be perpendicular to the long wire, either directed towards it or away, depending on the direction of current, still *in the plane of the coil.*
- However, the integration proved to be too problematic, and I can't include it here without a figure. Anyway, I wasn't able to obtain the final answer.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get$$F=\frac{\mu_0 I_1 I_2}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \frac{sin \theta\ d \theta}{\frac{a}{R} + sin \theta}$$in which $\theta$ is the angle around the coil measured from a radius parallel to the straight wire?

The wonderful Wolfram integration site gives the indefinite integral - quite a formidable looking expression. If I didn't want to cheat I'd expand $(\frac{a}{R}+sin\ \theta)^{-1}\ $ binomially for the case when $\frac{a}{R}>>1$.

Comment: I need to work on it, and your answer definitely serves as a useful reference point for where to go. Thanks, I've accepted and upvoted your answer!

Comment: By the way, did you mean *chords* parallel to the wire? There can only be two *radii* parallel to the wire.

Comment: Thank you. You have checked my formula, haven't you? And I meant one of those two radii ! That's alright, isn't it? $\theta$ is measured around the circle, so it would't make sense to start from a chord.

Comment: Got it now! :) I was thinking of angles subtended by chords parallel to the wire, at the centre, but now I understand.